# Intermittent map with bag file [closed]

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, rviz, bagfile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I am using a bag file to save my map made with hector_slam but when I start the bag file I see an intermittent map. Is there a way to see it continuously instead make it appear and disappear every second? Also can I only save the final image of the map? Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228276/intermittent-map-with-bag-file-%5Bclosed%5D/) by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2016-03-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved by opening rviz before open the bag file!

---

Originally posted by [papaclaudia](https://answers.ros.org/users/25634/papaclaudia/) with karma: 94 on 2016-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0